# Declare private static members in F#?

Tags: c#, class, f#

I decided to port the class in C# below to F# as an exercise.

It was difficult. I only notice three problems

1) Greet is visible
2) I can not get v to be a static class variable
3) I do not know how to set the greet member in the constructor.

How do i fix these? The code should be similar enough that i do not need to change any C# source. ATM only Test1.v = 21; does not work

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CsFsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test1.hi("stu");
            new Test1().hi();
            Test1.v = 21;
            var a = new Test1("Stan");
            a.hi();
            a.a = 9;

            Console.WriteLine("v = {0} {1} {2}", a.a, a.b, a.NotSTATIC());
        }
    }
    class Test1
    {
        public int a;
        public int b { get { return a * 2; } }
        string greet = "User";
        public static int v;

        public Test1() {}
        public Test1(string name) { greet = name; }

        public static void hi(string greet) { Console.WriteLine("Hi {0}", greet); }
        public void hi() { Console.WriteLine("Hi {0} #{1}", greet, v); }
        public int NotSTATIC() { return v; }
    }
}
```

F#

```
namespace CsFsTest

type Test1 = 
    (*
        public int a;
        public int b { get { return a * 2; } }
        string greet = "User";
        public static int v;
    *)
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable a : int
    member x.b = x.a * 2
    member x.greet = "User" (*!! Needs to be private *)

    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable v : int (*!! Needs to be static *)

    (*
        public Test1() {}
        public Test1(string name) { greet = name; }
    *)
    new () = {}
    new (name) = { }

    (*  
        public static void hi(string greet) { Console.WriteLine("Hi {0}", greet); }
        public void hi() { Console.WriteLine("Hi {0} #{1}", greet, v); }
        public int NotSTATIC() { return v; }
    *)   
    static member hi(greet) = 
        printfn "hi %s" greet
    member x.hi() =
        printfn "hi %s #%i" x.greet x.v
    member x.NotSTATIC() =
        x.v
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is some F# that compiles against the C# client.

In .NET, one very rarely exposes public fields; I would recommend against it.  The F# syntax for exposing fields is somewhat cumbersome.

```
namespace CsFsTest

open System

type Test1 =
    val mutable private greet : string
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable public a : int
    [<DefaultValue>]
    static val mutable private vv : int

    static member v with get() = Test1.vv 
                    and set(x) = Test1.vv <- x

    member this.b = this.a*2
    static member hi(greet:string) = Console.WriteLine("Hi {0}", greet)
    member this.hi() = Console.WriteLine("Hi {0} #{1}", this.greet, Test1.v)

    new() = { greet = "User" }
    new(name : string) = { greet = name }

    member this.NotSTATIC() = Test1.v
```

Answer (score 10):

The F# language has some constructs that don't have any equivalent in C#, but it has almost everything that you can use in C#. This means that if you simply translate code from C# to F#, you'll end up using only a subset of F#. As a result, it is sometimes better to look for some specific F# constructs.

I think this is also the case of static members. In addition to classes, you can also organize F# code using modules and modules provide a natural way for declaring static data and functions. Here is an example of module for greeting:

```
// modules are automatically 'static' (from the C# point of viedw)
module Greetings = 
  // public mutable field inside a module
  let mutable how = "Hello "
  // global function that uses the field
  let greet name = 
    Console.WriteLine(how + name)

// modify the global field and invoke global function
Greetings.how <- "Ahoj "
Greetings.greet("Tomas")
```

If you need some static functionality and some instance functionality, it is usually easy to split the functionality between a module and a standard class. The obvious benefit is that it gives you easier syntax, but it may also help structuring the code:

```
type Person(name) =
  member GreetMe() = 
    Greetings.greet(name)
```

Members inside module can be declared as `private` or `internal` if you want to keep them hidden from the user. For example if you wanted to make the `how` field accessible only to your assembly, you could write:

```
let mutable internal how = "Hello "
```

I think this gives you more idiomatic F# code, so I would probably prefer this style of programming when writing F# code. If you plan to use this from C#, then modules will appear as static classes, which are also easy to use.

As a side-note, it is generally recomended to avoid using too many mutable members. However, if you're using them for some kind of configuration then I suppose it is OK.

Comment: Right now i am only using them to so i know i can use them if i need to. As you can tell the class is mostly useless doing different things just so it can mess me up with gotchas. I almost quit before i got as far as i did.

Comment: Yes, I understand that your class is just an example to understand how to write some C# construct in F#. I wanted to give a broader answer to emphasize idiomatic F# programming style (perhaps just for the case when someone finds this question later). Anyway, you really don't need to worry about this kind of gotchas when learning F# (C# objects are just terribly complex!!)

Answer (score 2):

You're defining greet as a property.  It doesn't need to be one.

```
// these are the same
member x.greet = "User" 
member x.greet with get() = "User"
```

It can just be a variable.

```
val mutable private greet : string
new () = { greet = "User" }
new (name) = { greet = name }
```

F# doesn't allow you to have public static class variables.  You have to use a getter/setter.

Comment: You can hide F# module members using a .fsi file, making them functionally identical to private static functions.